# How to check for sd and transfer files automatically

Tags: sd-card, data-transfer

I was wondering how I could check for an sd card on my pi and once one is found it automatically transfers files from it to a usb/sd/hard drive.

Comment: I assume you mean an SD card connected through the USB ports? Because the Pi will boot (or attempt to boot), off any SD card in the SD card slot on the Pi. This would be fairly easy to do with something like a Bash script. A starting point would be looking into the commands required for mounting USB drives and transferring files. You haven't specified what OS you are using but Raspbian Jessie is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I use a python script to check for mounted drives on a headless pi. There will be a dozen other ways so this may not be the best for you?

This script makes a directory to mount a drive. Then it checks if sda1 is mounted if not it tries to mount it. If the mount is successful it deletes any old trash files to make space for your new stuff.

```
import os
import subprocess

print ('')
print ('Making directory to mount flash drive to..')
os.system('sudo mkdir -p /media/exthdd')
# Mount the drive
print ('Mounting the drive flash...')


def tryMounting(retest=False):

    try:
        sda1 = subprocess.check_output(['mount | grep sda1'], shell=True)

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        if retest == True:
            # You may not want this error?
            print ('#############################')
            print ('!!!  No flash drive found !!!')
            print ('#############################')

            time.sleep(5)
            return 0
        else:
            print ('No drive found, trying to mount sda1...')
            os.system('sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/exthdd -o umask=000')
            tryMounting(True)

    print ('Drive mounted at /media/exthdd')
    return 1

flash_drive_attached = tryMounting()

if flash_drive_attached >0:
    # Search for trash folders on flash drive and delete 
    dirList = (os.listdir('/media/exthdd'))
    if '.Trashes' in dirList:
        subprocess.Popen('sudo rm -r .Trashes', shell=True).wait()
        print ('Flash drive waste bin emptied')
   #This is where the specifics of your copy command go, it'll be something like...
   source ='path to stuff to copy'
   destination = '/media/exthdd/path to save to'
   subprocess.Popen('cp -Rv %s %s' %(source, destination))
```

Hope that sets you off in a useful direction!
You could set this to run with a cron job?
It will fall down if you don't want to save to the first drive inserted.
If it's always the same drive you could check it with:

```
df -h
```